# How can I switch the language of my page and stay at the scrolled position of the page?

Tags: php, html

I want to switch the language of my page. This works very well:

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Cache-control: private'); // IE 6 FIX
if(isSet($_GET['lang'])) {
    $lang = $_GET['lang'];
    // register the session and set the cookie
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
    setcookie("lang", $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
} else if(isSet($_SESSION['lang'])) {
    $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
} else if(isSet($_COOKIE['lang'])) {
    $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
} else {
    $lang = 'en';
}
switch ($lang) {
    case 'en':
        $lang_file = 'lang.en.php';
        break;
    case 'de':
        $lang_file = 'lang.de.php';
        break;
    default:
        $lang_file = 'lang.de.php';
}
include_once 'languages/' . $lang_file;
?>
```

If I click on for example "English"...

```
  <a href="index.php?lang=en">English</a>
  <a href="index.php?lang=de">German</a>
```

...my English page version is loaded like this:

```
www.mypage.php?lang=en
```

My problem is: when I scroll down the page and then click on another language,the page loads at the top position. But I would like the page to stay at the scrolled position. (Actually when I just refresh the page, then my page keeps staying at the scrolled position.)

Comment: Of course it doesn’t behave the same as a simple refresh - because you are loading a _different URL_, and that is totally unknown to the browser, it has no idea what data that will deliver and how large the content will be. So if you want a feature like that, you have to implement it yourself - get current scroll position with JavaScript, store it somewhere, and then apply it again when the other language version is loaded.

Comment: (But unless your site is explicitly about comparing languages or something like that, I’d say it is a rather useless feature. Normal users don’t usually switch between languages halfway through a piece of content, they decide upfront which version they want to read.)

Comment: @CBroe Thank you very much! This helps me

Answer (score 1):

You can take English and German in a span with unique id like this

```
<a href="index.php?lang=en#unique_id_for_english"><span id="unique_id_for_english">English<span></a>
<a href="index.php?lang=de#unique_id_for_german"><span id="unique_id_for_german">German<span></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

You will have to use

```
 event.preventDefault();
```

On your a tag, this way it will stop the default reload which causes the page to refresh to the top.

for example

```
$('a').click(function () {
     event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I tested this, now none of my buttons are working anymore